# how to Save PrintDocument .PrinterSettings in a file so that user have not to select printer settings everytime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am printing a document using print preview and every-time user click to print the data a dialogue asking for printer settings gets prompted which is of course not good. So, in order to remove that print dialogue box I need to store the print dialogue settings some where on the hard disk.

**Code**

```
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
        PrintDialog pdi = new PrintDialog();
        pdi.Document = pd;
        if (pdi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            doc.PrinterSettings = pdi.PrinterSettings;
            pd.Print();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Print Cancelled");
        }
```

**Problem**

how to store print dialog setting in some format and retrieve and store it in the object?

P.S: settings should be saved for the next time when the application is restarted.

Comment: The first option that comes to mind is to use application settings for each individual value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a setting key in Setting file of your project and choose [System.drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) type for it and name it for example PrinterSettins. Then you can save your printer settings in this property or read from this property simply.

Also you can create some setting keys for individual properties of `PrinterSettings` like `PrinterName` save them.

**Save:**

```
if(printDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
{
   Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterSettings = printDialog1.PrinterSettings;
   //Properties.Settings.PrinterName = printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

**Read:**

```
printDocument1.PrinterSettings = Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterSettings;
//printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterName;
```

[image]

Note:

- [How to: Add or Remove Application Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/25zf0ze8.aspx)

### **EDIT**

Since `PrinterSettings` class is serializable, another solution is to convert it to a base64 string and save it in a string and restore it from string. So you can create a string setting key `PrinterSettings` and save `PrinterSettings` in it or restore from it:

**Save:**

```
Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterSettings=SettingToString( printDialog1.PrinterSettings);
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

**Read:**

```
printDocument1.PrinterSettings = SettingFromString(Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterSettings);
```

**Helper Methods:**

```
private string SettingToString(PrinterSettings settings)
{
    if (settings == null)
        return null;

    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, settings);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
}

private PrinterSettings SettingFromString(string base64)
{
    try
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64)))
        {
            return (PrinterSettings)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return new PrinterSettings();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it work for the next time when the application is restarted?

Comment: Yes, settings infrastructure is designed for such cases.

Comment: how to create setting key?

Comment: You can also use settings for saving individual properties of PrinterSettings if you prefer.

Comment: This is sooo good!! Forget about the buggy XML serializer which forgets to add important fields!!