# Can I share PrinterSettings between multiple computers?

Tags: c#, winforms, network-printers

I have documents that need to be sent to the same network printer from multiple computers.  I can save (serialize) a `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings` object and recall it on the same machine, but I am wondering how that works across multiple computers.

Obviously, if I'm printing to a local printer, this isn't going to work, but will it work for network printers?  If so, does the name of the printer have to be consistent?

I cannot find any Microsoft documentation on this subject.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33184970/3110834). You can save it into the `Settings` of your application before distributing the application. Then all instances will use the same default settings. Another option is sharing the serialized value using a file share or using database.

Comment: The printer settings are for a specific printer, which is indicated by name. If the names aren't the same, it most likely wouldn't work. Have you considered configuring the printer itself instead?

Comment: @KenWhite What do you mean by configuring the printer?

Comment: Set the printer to default to the same settings, so that each user just sends a job to the printer and it prints them the same way. You can also configure most printers with named or numbered print jobs, which means that if you say *Print this document using the settings for job "invoice"* it will use those settings for the document.

Comment: The problem is each computer needs to send different documents to different printers.  I'll look into the numbered print jobs.